# How to get the first occurrence of a tag using SImple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, dom

i'm trying to parse an html page and get the first occurrence of a tag using method `find`.. this is what i try

```
$master = file_get_html($link);
$link1 = $master->find("span.cl");
```

i need to do something like

```
$link1[0]
```

is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$link1  = $master->find('a', 0);
```

this finds the first `<a>` for example.